# Messaging technologies between applications ?

Tags: .net, protocol, messaging

Recently, I had to create a program to send messages between two winforms executable. I used a [tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47341/NET-Interprocess-Communication-Revisited) with simple built-in functionalities to prevent having to figure out all the ins and outs of this vast quantity of protocols that exist.

But now, I'm ready to learn more about the internals difference between each of theses protocols. I googled a couple of them but it would be greatly appreciate to have a good reference book that gives me a clean idea of how each protocol works and what are the pros and cons in a couple of context.

Here is a list of nice protocols that I found:

- Shared memory
- TCP
- List item
- Named Pipe
- File Mapping
- Mailslots
- MSMQ (Microsoft Queue Solution)
- WCF

I know that all of these protocols are not specific to a language, it would be nice if example could be in .net.

Thank you very much.

Comment: are you looking on how to design a SOA (Service oriented architecture) ?

Comment: @ElYusubov, No, I just looking for how all of these protocols works at a very low level in Windows specifically.

Comment: Windows System Programming, Third Edition - look at that book

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the scenarios are supported through bindings in WCF.

For the official source you may look at [WCF Feature Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733103), and good intro to [Basic WCF Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731067), and very detailed [Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936243.aspx) is also availiable in MSDN.

Regarding books, the top rated book on this subject matter can be found here - [Programming WCF Services](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596526997)

Comment: I know that WCF is a very powerful technology but in a lot of situations, it's like moving a canned food of beans with a very large boat. This is the reason why I want to have a deep explanation of each of these protocols.

Comment: I am afraid there is no single book that would describe all listed protocols in detail. However, you may look at "Windows System Programming, Third Edition" which has topic on Interprocess communication, featuring pipes and mailslots.

Comment: Thanks to you @ElYusubov, the book explain in deep details names pipe and mail slots.

Answer (score 1):

For MSMQ solution, take a look at [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com/). It is very easy to set up and play around with. They have plenty of examples that you can download and run.

We have used it in a number of applications and it works great so far.

There are also some similar alternatives, such as [MassTransit](http://code.google.com/p/masstransit/).